# R String Padding for Times

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe with a column representing times. However, the length of the strings are not consistent and when I try to convert them I get NAs:

Is there a way to pad the 5 character times so that all values in the column are a total of 7 characters?

```
times <- c("56:09", "1:05:19", "1:06:24", "1:07:22", "51:50", "57:51", "41:45", "58:25", "46:45", "58:52")
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a condition with `nchar` in `ifelse` and convert to Time using `as.ITime` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(ifelse(nchar(times) < 7, paste0("0:", times), times))
#[1] "00:56:09" "01:05:19" "01:06:24" "01:07:22" "00:51:50" "00:57:51" "00:41:45" "00:58:25" "00:46:45" "00:58:52"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this also works:

```
times[which(nchar(times)==5)] <- paste0("00:", times[which(nchar(times)==5)])
```